# In Sails.js, can I define URL slugs in the controller rather than in the routes.js?

Tags: javascript, routes, sails.js

I know I can use URL slugs in routes.js:

```
'get /:account/:repo': {
   controller: 'RepoController',
   action: 'show',
   skipAssets: true
}
```

How can I do this in a controller?

```
module.exports = {
    index: (req, res) => res.view('home'),

    'get /:account/:repo': (req, res) => {
        let account = req.param('account')
        let repo = req.param('repo')
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/url-slugs), the following route will try to call RepoController's `show` action,

```
'get /:account/:repo': {
   controller: 'RepoController',
   action: 'show',
   skipAssets: true
 }
```

and in **RepoController**, define `show` action

```
module.exports = {
  index: (req, res) => res.view('home'),

  show : (req, res) => {
    let account = req.param('account')
    let repo = req.param('repo')
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that. I want to do define the `:account` and `:repo` in the controller, and not in the routes, if possible.

Comment: I doubt that it's possible. Separating routes and controller seems good approach. You should stick with it.